# bspwm workspaces in Xfce4 not working

Tags: linux, manjaro, xfce4

I have been running bspwm as a standalone desktop for a while, but I found it kind of a pain to have to manage wifi, xinput settings, themes, etc without a proper DE, so I switched to Xfce4 and replaced xfwm with bspwm. I got sxhkd to work fine, and bspwm mostly works, but without any ability to switch workspaces. I usually keep 10 workspaces open, so I've set 10 workspaces in the Xfce workspace settings, but I can't seem to find a way to switch through them.

The xfce4-panel doesn't show but 1 workspace, and Polybar shows 'Desktop' where it used to show 1-10. Xfce-panel runs with a warning 'No window manager on screen 0', but xrandr says I'm currently on screen 0, and bspwm is definitely running. I can't tell if it's an Xfce or bspwm problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve only got one monitor, but I was specifying which output the workspaces should go to. I removed that, and it worked after changing

```
bspc monitor eDP1 -d 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

to

```
bspc monitor -d 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Not sure why that was making a difference, but figured I’d leave the question and my solution up.